# Cannot connect to iTunes Store in Mac OS X Lion without any error messages

Tags: itunes, macos, itunes-store

I can no longer connect to the iTunes Store on my Mac.

My iTunes is from 10.6.3 (now updated to 10.7.4).

When I try to connect to the iTunes Store, the following error is occurring and indicating no access to the store.

[image: error message dialog]

I have internet connection and I can also open websites in Safari, Chrome, Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't posted any specific troubleshooting steps taken the best course of action would be to use the help menu in iTunes and search for "cannot connect to the iTunes store".

Alternatively, you can search http://apple.com/support under iTunes and see if you can find an article that might help you narrow down the causes of this problem.